# Randomizar a posição das imagens

Tags: jquery, css3

Tenho uma lista com 10 imagens e preciso fazer com que cada vez que houver um *refresh* na página essas imagens mudem de posição.

Comment: Breno, bem vindo! Se você colocar aqui o código HTML das imagens que têm, vai ter uma resposta acertada.

Comment: Você pode explicar melhor o que você quer fazer, especialmente o "mudem de posição"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assumindo que quando você diz "tenho uma lista com 10 imagens" você se refere a algo como:

```
<ul id="minhaLista">
    <li><img src=... /></li>
    <li><img src=... /></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Se você quer essas imagens numa ordem aleatória, eu sugiro usar o [algoritmo de Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
var ul = $("#minhaLista");
var lis = $.makeArray(ul.children().detach()); // Remove todos os lis e converte num array
for ( var i = 0 ; i < lis.length ; i++ ) {
    var proxima = Math.floor(Math.random()*(lis.length - i) + i); // Sorteia um
    ul.append(lis[proxima]); // Coloca de volta na lista
    lis[proxima] = lis[i];  // Retira ele dos "ainda não sorteados"
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/ZmXgf/).

Se seu objetivo por outro lado for que uma imagem aleatória seja a "primeira", mas as demais continuem na mesma ordem (como se você tivesse "passado pra frente" um número aleatório de vezes), é só sortear uma imagem e passar todas as anteriores pro final da lista:

```
var ul = $("#minhaLista");
var lis = ul.children();
var sorteada = Math.floor(Math.random()*lis.length);
for ( var i = 0 ; i < sorteada ; i++ )
    lis.eq(i).detach().appendTo(ul);
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/ZmXgf/1/).

Comment: Sua resposta é melhor que a minha. Pode anotar que ela exige jQuery?

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Eu achei desnecessário, uma vez que a tag jquery está na pergunta (em geral, perguntas com a tag javascript somente "pedem" uma resposta em JavaScript puro, enquanto pergunta com a tag jquery já deixa implícito que as respostas podem envolver jQuery). De todo modo, dei +1 no seu comentário, isso deve se suficiente pra chamar a atenção para o fato.

Comment: Bem lembrado. A questão nem mesmo está tageada com javascript, mas sim só jquery. Você está certo.

Answer (score 2):

Um jeito de fazer isso, usando javascript puro e sem jQuery está listado abaixo

```
/**
 * Shuffle Fisher-Yates algorithm
 * 
 * @see http://sroucheray.org/blog/2009/11/array-sort-should-not-be-used-to-shuffle-an-array/
 * @param   {Array}   array
 * @returns {Array}
 */
function shuffle (array) {
    var i = array.length, j, temp;
    if (i === 0) {
        return array;
    }
    while (--i) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

/**
 * Para um elemento pai e um array contendo nomes de arquivos, adiciona randomicamente filhos a este pai.
 * 
 * @param   {DOMElement}   el      Elemento pai. Ex: document.getElementById('id-do-elemento'), jQuery('#id-do-elemento')
 * @param   {Array}        array   Array contendo a parte que muda do local da imagem
 * @param   {String}       [base]  Base do caminho
 * @returns {DOMElement}
 */
function randonImgAppendChild (el, array, base) {
    var i, base = base || '', img;
    array = shuffle(array);

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        img = new Image(); // Imagem. Poderia ser qualquer outro elemento
        img.src  = base + array[i];
        el.appendChild(img);
    }
    return el;
}
```

No caso, a função `shuffle` é usada para randomizar um array (`Array.sort` e `Math.randon` não são muito eficientes dependendo de como são usadas), e a função `randonImgAppendChild` é que efetivamente faz o serviço. O código está comentado então é só ler nele.

Exemplo de uso:

```
randonImgAppendChild(document.body, ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg', '10.jpg'], '/pasta/base/');
randonImgAppendChild(document.getElementById('mainbar'), ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg', '10.jpg'], '/pasta/base/');
```

Nota: a resposta anterior estava [baseada na resposta do SO de extramaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14004417/894546), porém ela não é muito boa.

Comment: Para quem quer uma solução em jQuery em vez de javascript puro, a resposta do @mgibsonbr é melhor

Comment: Uma coisa que não entendi nem na sua resposta nem na original do extramaster é o valor do `for`: por que `23` (ou `18`)? Na pergunta linkada, o OP queria 16 imagens vindas de um conjunto de 10 (aí faz mais sentido, mas na minha leitura ainda deveria ser `16`). Tem alguma razão pra esse número?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Editei a resposta. Agora definitivamente está compreensível. Mais fácil fazer direito do que explicar a POG do cara.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Renomeie as imagem de 1 a 10, por exemplo:

```
1.jpg, 2.jpg e assim por diante.
```

2 - Adicione um id ao elemento onde ficaram as imagens, por exemplo:

id="bannerRandom"

```
var totalCount = 10;
function ChangeIt(){
  var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
  document.getElementById("bannerRandom").style.backgroundImage = "url('/images/"+num+".jpg')";
}
```

no url, passe o local onde estão localizada as imagens.

Lembrando que dessa forma as imagens não vão seguir uma ordem e sim vão apresentadas randomicamente.

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver usando **PHP**, isso vai lhe ajudar:

```
$randomImg = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg', 'img5.jpg', 'img6.jpg', 'img7.jpg', 'img8.jpg', 'img9.jpg', 'img10.jpg'];
shuffle($randomImg);
echo $randomImg[0];
```

prefiro fazer nele próprio do que no css/javascript