# Trocar a posição das imagens

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma lista com 21 imagens, dispostas numa grade de 3 colunas e 7 linhas, e preciso fazer com que cada vez que houver um refresh na página, ou ela for acessada por um outro IP, essas imagens mudem de posição, de modo que a imagem na posição 1 vá para a posição 2, a imagem na posição 2 vá para a posição 3, e assim sucessivamente.

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: O que você fez até então? Inclua o código que tem até agora, procure sempre incluir um [mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), isto facilita a lhe ajudar. Do jeito que está parece pura e simplesmente que você quer que seja feito para você.

Comment: É que não tenho experiência nenhuma com isso.
Lista de imagens:
<ul id="minhaLista">
    <li>Imagem 1</li>
    <li>Imagem 2</li>
    <li>Imagem 3</li>
    <li>Imagem 4</li>
    <li>Imagem 5</li>
    <li>Imagem 6</li>
    <li>Imagem 7</li>
    <li>Imagem 8</li>
    <li>Imagem 9</li>
    <li>Imagem 10</li>
</ul>

Código:
var ul = $("#minhaLista");
var lis = ul.children();
var sorteada = Math.floor(Math.random()*lis.length);
for ( var i = 0 ; i < sorteada ; i++ )
    lis.eq(i).detach().appendTo(ul);

Assim, as imagens estão se alternando randomicamente. Gostaria que fosse em ordem.

Comment: Este tópico quase resolveu...
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4654/randomizar-a-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-das-imagens?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

De uma olhada neste exemplo talvez possa lhe ajudar.

**Coloque o código javascript no final da página**.

*Quando atualizar a página terá as imagens em posições diferentes.*

**Certifique-se que seu código tenha o plugin para jquery.**.

```html
        <div class="band">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="member">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQVvDaaOhX5qQqceSi3ig_KqadYZh4jCatnnCrXb6Hky5PxJ69e"></img>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="member">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQTUs-q4L6_5h796EcaqbamcUU2K6M8ofHH747nXmT30Lcvbe3f"></img>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="member">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT18KP4pLbzFQ1fE636tJ8wvhDuNUy-iQuFSSUghW-0_ZefmuWs"></img>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="member">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQVvDaaOhX5qQqceSi3ig_KqadYZh4jCatnnCrXb6Hky5PxJ69e"></img>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="member">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_DY2Nn9Jps_xTbUpRY7wWAEA7FiJAtN0IPaDBbFoGmiLWS2hI5Q"></img>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="member">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT18KP4pLbzFQ1fE636tJ8wvhDuNUy-iQuFSSUghW-0_ZefmuWs"></img>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="member">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdP1LO4b1TWv4VH-GJiX2P4lgd0ad1cD36yskPCjHlQVBFBcka"></img>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="member">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTEgpfDDHkNAkp0YcHVNCnJzXhlt2RP14SzsKjsR5WrshWEgaMd"></img>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="member">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT18KP4pLbzFQ1fE636tJ8wvhDuNUy-iQuFSSUghW-0_ZefmuWs"></img>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="member">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQnf80rzHvYlbwU6_N9UjbDP_TbVc4DcaArubV__aobVp9pHFAF"></img>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="member">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRigN44ISilbS0YQhNcbw_85Vq0K4CvS_eUc29b5QOhBiarQy7FAg"></img>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="member">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRA9kDuINLMU4kSvZeYMGoRx5tE3hPTQm4URfEMcHCQ7iYeGqInSg"></img>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("div.band").randomize("table tr td", "div.member");
});

(function ($) {
  $.fn.randomize = function (tree, childElem) {
   return this.each(function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     if (tree)
        $this = $(this).find(tree);
   var unsortedElems = $this.children(childElem);
   var elems = unsortedElems.clone();

   elems.sort(function () {
       return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);
   });

    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
        unsortedElems.eq(i).replaceWith(elems[i]);
   });
 };
})(jQuery);
```